# Dividing a list of 2 query statements

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have some query statements and I want to take the average by basically doing     `top_level_comment_count.fdiv(code_review_assigned_count).round(2)`

Here are my 2 query statements:

```
top_level_comment_count = CrucibleComment.group(:user_id).where(parent_comment_id: nil).count
code_review_assigned_count = Reviewer.group(:user_id).count
```

Both of these return something that looks like this:

```
 40=>5,
 41=>1,
 43=>4,
 44=>10,
 45=>2,
 46=>13,
 48=>7,
 50=>7,
 51=>6,
 52=>5,
 54=>7,
 55=>41,
 56=>2,
 58=>21,
 60=>7,
 61=>8,
 62=>3,
 63=>1,
```

So, what I am wanting to do is if the :user_ids are the same, take the average.
My def currently looks like this:

```
  def self.average_top_level_comments
    a = CrucibleComment.group(:user_id).where(parent_comment_id: nil).count
    b = Reviewer.group(:user_id).count
  end
```

In other words I am wanting to do this statement:

```
return nil unless code_review_assigned_count && top_level_comment_count
top_level_comment_count.fdiv(code_review_assigned_count).round(2)
```

for a group of numbers. How can I do this?

```
For example:
id:40 => 5.0/3.3
id: 41 => 1/2.2
id: 43 => 4 /1.0
```

Comment: Can you show the data where you derived the 3.3, 2.2, and 1.0?

Comment: @coenwulf that is the data from b = Reviewer.group(:user_id).count,   id:40 => 3.3, id:41 => 2.2

Comment: Hmm. How is count returning counts of records that aren't integers? for `Reviewer.group(:user_id).count` I'd expect to see something like: `{40 => 2, 41 => 18, ...}`

Comment: err sorry, it is returning integers. i was saying that because it's group by user_id

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

Something like:

`division_result = top_level_comment_count.inject({}) do |result, item|
  id = item.first
  count = item.last
  result[id] = count.to_f / code_review_assigned_count[id]
  result
end`

That will return a hash with the IDs as keys and the results of the division as the values.

Comment: So, would I have this in my   def self.average_top_level_comments
where I first gather the query statements and rest of the code?

Comment: Sure. That makes sense